# PostgreSQL loop query for report with changing variables

Tags: php, postgresql

I have to prepare each month several individual reports where I make the same query in the database, is like the total purchases for each client with some details. So my query is something like this:

```
Select order_no, date, item, total 
from purchase_orders
where client_id'5' and fec_rec between '2024-02-01'and'2024-02-29'
```

I print the results into a PDF file.

So I have to do this almost 300 times, 1 time per client.

My idea is to declare all the clien_id as variables, and then run a script or loop to process all the clients and at each client print a specific pdf file.

I have no clue about loop methods or declaring variables on postgresql.
My database is PostgreSQL 9.3 and I have a web server with PHP where I can put and run the code.
Looked all around to figure the best way out for this, but I'm stucked due to my poor programming knowledge. All the results I've found were oriented on mysql databases, I can't find the way to bond the mysql examples using a postgresql query.

Answer (score 0):

Your description implies you create a PDF for each client. Whether this is correct or not you would be much better off to run a single query and get all clients. Then iterate the result spinning off PDF(s) necessary. Without the definition (ddl) for you table I cannot give an exact query but what you posted becomes something like:

```
Select client_id, order_no, date, item, total 
  from purchase_orders
 where fec_rec between '2024-02-01' and '2024-02-29'
 order by client_id, fec_rec;
```

Finally, Postgres 9.2 really? That version reached [end-of-life](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/), meaning no further support or updates, in 2017. I suggest you update your version soon.

Comment: Yes, the task is to create 1 pdf for each client. I've simplified the query on the example to get an idea of what I'm trying to do, but it has more issues.

The query for the report consist in 2 selects and 1 union,(sends and returns) and the arguments for returns implies that client_id is excluded from some columns, which makes me impossible to run a simple query to retrieve all the results and then iterate them.

That's why I'm looking for a way to process the query with a script where client_id is a declared variable and process que query for each variable and get a result for each one.

Comment: Regarding the Postgres 9.3, yes, I'm aware I should upgrade it to a newer version, in fact I've installed a newer version in a test enviroment but it doesn't work properly with the application (also obsolete), that's why we're unable to upgrade yet.